# Download all files from webform

Tags: 7, webforms

I need to download a zip with all attached files from a webform.

Is it possible?

Comment: Yes, it is possible, but there are different ways of doing it depending on your requisites: any a user can download it? if not, which users? For al webforms? for a certain webform? for a certain weform submit? Which version of Drupal? You should give more details if you want a good answer.

Answer (score -1):

Webform stores all these files in sites/default/files/webform you can download them with FTP.